410 (Gone) HTTP status code, Connector configuration gone error thrown in New teams
When i configure a connector in the New Teams then we are not receiving any messages in the channel, because invalid webhook URL is obtained (using SDK method) which returns a 410 (Gone) HTTP status code when we make the POST call on that webhook URL.
This issue is specifically encountered in new teams not in classic teams

Hii @Hasit Parmar Could you please refer this sample-https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/incoming-webhook
